# How to send one contact address as OSMAnd destination?

Tags: contacts, osmand

My contacts all ahve their address set, and I would like to be able to navigate to their addresses using OSMAnd. Unfortunatly, clicking the "share" button, don't allow me to share that contact using OSMAnd, but only through mail, bluetooth, K9Mail, ...

How can I have the contact address sent to OSMAnd ?

Comment: What phone do you have? Different phones have different contacts apps.

Comment: I have a Wiko Raimbow using "standard" Google Contacts app.

Comment: Can't you just click on the address to get a choice of navigation apps?

Comment: Indeed, this starts OSMAnd, but strangely, the address can't be found.

Comment: It sounds like Nominatim (or whichever address-lookup service OSMAnd uses) simply doesn't know that address. Since it's OpenStreetMap, you can edit OSM to add it, but that's a separate issue from getting the address into OSMAnd.